# Crystal Formula Suppress Box Object Working While Debuging Not When Published C# & ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I have a pretty standard Suppress Formula written which works whilst i'm viewing my report in debug mode

```
if ({DataTable.order_qty}-{DataTable.complete_qty}) > 0 then true
```

When I've published the report it loads fine.  My formula's to suppress sections or fields seem to work.  however i have a box object and a line object which stop working after publish.

The Box Object and Line Object are shown and never suppress.  I tried reversing the formula to suggest that they start suppressed and open but it seems they are ignored.

The server that hosts the website had Crystal Runtime 13.0.12 installed.  The report was developed using reports for visual studio 13.0.19 in Visual Studio 2015.

I proceeded to update the server addition to 13.0.19.  I can't test this just yet as i need to reboot at a closure time.

However i don't know if that will resolve the issue so hoping that someone may have experienced this before and has a quick answer.

What might i be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Updating the server version to match the developers version was the correct solution.  hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Just to clarify,

I updated my server version of the crystal reports runtime to match the same version as my crystal developers version for visual studio.